# $48$ reasons why a matrix is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Currently using the MIT recordings from Prof.Strang to review [deduction of the determinant formula](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-19-determinant-formulas-and-cofactors/).

Let's say we take a closer look at

$$
\left\vert\begin{array}{c c}
a & 0\\
c & 0
\end{array}\right\vert
$$

And to quote from the transcript:

> Why is that determinant nothing, forget him?
>
> Well, it has a column of zeros.
>
> And by the -- well, so one way to think is, well, it's a singular matrix.
>
> Oh, for, for like forty-eight different reasons. That determinant is zero.

Now $48$, that's an oddly specific number. And while I do believe he was exaggerating, it did make me curious about just how many reasons (the determinant's being zero not included, of course) there really *are* for that matrix' being singular.

What are they?

Comment: What is the "reason" exactly? It is not a formal mathematical notion, you can't say that some proposition has exactly N reasons. It (proposition) can be just true or false; provable or unprovable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are $23$ equivalent conditions for a matrix to be nonsingular; just take the negation of each statement and you have $23$ conditions for a matrix to be singular:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

Comment: Some of those 23 reasons do not qualify in my opinion. For example, some negations seem quite hard to prove without falling back to another criterion (#1, #9, #10), one is just self-referential (#11), and one is explicitly forbidden by the question (#19 `;)` ).

Comment: @T.Verron: I dunno; it seems pretty clear that row operations cannot create a nonzero entry in the second column (#1), or that the product of any matrix with the zero column is still zero (#9).

Answer (score 5):

I am sure that 48 is a humorously specific way of saying "many ways." In the lecture context described, I interpret the question to mean, "In how many different ways can someone trained in linear algebra see, at a glance, that this matrix is singular?"  Two reasons should count as different so long as the mental process of checking them is even a little bit different, even though they are probably logically equivalent (almost trivially so).

To avoid casework, I'll presume for simplicity's sake that $a\neq 0\neq c$ in $A=\left[\begin{matrix}a&0\\c&0\end{matrix}\right]$.

1. There is a column of 0's.
2. The second row $[c\;0]$ is a scalar multiple of the first row $[a\;0]$.
3. The second column is a scalar multiple of the first column.
4. The rows are not linearly independent, since $c[a\;0] -a[c\;0]=[0\;0]$.
5. The columns are not linearly independent, since $0\left[\begin{matrix}a\\c\end{matrix}\right]+1\left[\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right]$.
6. Quickly row-reducing the matrix yields that its reduced echelon form is $\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right]\neq I$.
7. The product $\left[\begin{matrix}a&0\\c&0\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right]$.
8. The map $\vec{x}\mapsto A\vec{x}$ is not one-to-one, because $A\left[\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right] = A\left[\begin{matrix}0\\0\end{matrix}\right]$.
9. Since $x_1 \begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix} + x_2 \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} = x_1\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}$, the column space of $A$ is one-dimensional (all scalar multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}$), not $\mathbb{R}^2$.
10. The row space is clearly $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&0\end{bmatrix}: x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}\neq\mathbb{R}^2$, so $A$ is not invertible.
11. Since $\begin{bmatrix}a&0&1\\c&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ row-reduces to $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, the equation $A\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ has no solution.
12. Since $A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\vec{0}=0\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, we see that $0$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

I'm far short of 48, but I'm getting tired already.